# What are (if any) the benefits of dual booting a Linux distro alongside Windows instead of using Virtualbox?

Tags: linux, windows-10, virtualbox, centos, multi-boot

I am a web developer who uses Linux (CentOs) A lot! Running Linux within windows via Virtualbox causes me some minor issues and performance lags. I was thinking about creating a partition to boot my laptop with Linux every time I need to work on my projects.

So, I am wandering are there any benefits as well as drawbacks to dualbooting linux instead of using it via virtualbox?

Comment: There are pros and cons associated with either method (dual-boot versus virtualization), but let me just say this:  while I am relatively new to being a Super User contributor, I have visited the site several times each day throughout the past two months.  During that time, I have easily lost count of the number of questions posed by people who encountered some type of problem with their Windows/Linux dual-boot configuration. Faced with the same decision, I would stick with VirtualBox and probably consider the native Hyper-V possibilities, also. It just seems to be a more stable configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The benefits of dual booting are:

- no performance overhead from the host OS
- direct hardware access (sometimes required for special hardware)
- direct manipulation of files on the opposite OS partition
- less total memory required

You are probably already aware of most of the benefits of virtualization, but some less obvious ones are:

- easily test network related functions between host and guest
- snapshots allow instant rollback to previous state
- easily migrate to different hardware
- VM hardware is typically recognized by the OS without special drivers
- easy to clone for A/B testing of different configurations
- no need to mess around with bootloaders!